# A semi-implicit Euler scheme: does this exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider an ODE
$$
y'(t)=f(y(t))+u(t),
$$
where $u(t)$ is an external input. The explicit and implicit Euler method read
\begin{align}
\text{Explicit Euler:} \quad &y_{t+h}=y_t + h(f(y_t)+u(t)), \\
\text{Implicit Euler:} \quad &y_{t+h}=y_t + h(f(y_{t+h})+u(t+h)),
\end{align}
where $h>0$ is the time step and $y_t \approx y(t)$.

I was wondering whether a method that is implicit in the state variable and explicit in the input exists, i.e.,
$$
y_{t+h}=y_t + h(f(y_{t+h})+u(t)).
$$
I imagine that such a method would inherit the convergence properties of the explicit and implicit Euler methods (1st order accuracy), and would expect that it is as stable as the implicit Euler method.

Is there any reference on this?

Comment: How smooth is $u$? If it is not differentiable, there might be slight differences between the two processes that reduce slower than $O(h)$ or, this is speculation, might even stay apart in extra special examples (involving nowhere differentiable functions or worse).

Comment: Let’s say $u$ is smooth. I think if you have $C^1$ Lipschitz then the three methods should be equivalent up to $O(h^2)$. By the way you need this for convergence anyway? What about stability?

Comment: Stability is only influenced by the part of the ODE that depends on $y$. So as long as $u$ is not computed from the current or a delayed state of $y$, there should be no problem.